# mvn clean install returning build failed when installing PL/Java

Tags: postgresql, maven, pljava

I am trying to install PL/Java on Ubuntu 16.0.4 and getting `PL/Java backend native code ........................ FAILURE` error when running `mvn clean install` command. Complete error logs are given below.

**PostgreSQL version - 11**
**Ubuntu Version - 16.0.4**

```
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Reactor Build Order:
[INFO] 
[INFO] PostgreSQL PL/Java
[INFO] PL/Java API
[INFO] PL/Java backend Java code
[INFO] PL/Java backend native code
[INFO] PL/Java Deploy
[INFO] PL/Java Ant tasks
[INFO] PL/Java examples
[INFO] PL/Java packaging
[INFO]                                                                         
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building PostgreSQL PL/Java 1.5.2
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-clean-plugin:2.5:clean (default-clean) @ pljava.app ---
[INFO] Deleting /home/dataguise/Downloads/pljava-1_5_2/target
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-site-plugin:3.4:attach-descriptor (attach-descriptor) @ pljava.app ---
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-install-plugin:2.5.2:install (default-install) @ pljava.app ---
[INFO] Installing /home/dataguise/Downloads/pljava-1_5_2/pom.xml to /home/dataguise/.m2/repository/org/postgresql/pljava.app/1.5.2/pljava.app-1.5.2.pom
[INFO] Installing /home/dataguise/Downloads/pljava-1_5_2/target/pljava.app-1.5.2-site.xml to /home/dataguise/.m2/repository/org/postgresql/pljava.app/1.5.2/pljava.app-1.5.2-site.xml
[INFO]                                                                         
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building PL/Java API 1.5.2
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-clean-plugin:2.5:clean (default-clean) @ pljava-api ---
[INFO] Deleting /home/dataguise/Downloads/pljava-1_5_2/pljava-api/target
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:3.0.1:resources (default-resources) @ pljava-api ---
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] skip non existing resourceDirectory /home/dataguise/Downloads/pljava-1_5_2/pljava-api/src/main/resources
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:2.5.1:compile (default-compile) @ pljava-api ---
[INFO] Compiling 24 source files to /home/dataguise/Downloads/pljava-1_5_2/pljava-api/target/classes
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:3.0.1:testResources (default-testResources) @ pljava-api ---
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] skip non existing resourceDirectory /home/dataguise/Downloads/pljava-1_5_2/pljava-api/src/test/resources
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:2.5.1:testCompile (default-testCompile) @ pljava-api ---
[INFO] No sources to compile
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-surefire-plugin:2.17:test (default-test) @ pljava-api ---
[INFO] No tests to run.
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:3.0.1:copy-resources (copy-service-config) @ pljava-api ---
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] Copying 1 resource
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-jar-plugin:2.6:jar (default-jar) @ pljava-api ---
[INFO] Building jar: /home/dataguise/Downloads/pljava-1_5_2/pljava-api/target/pljava-api-1.5.2.jar
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-site-plugin:3.4:attach-descriptor (attach-descriptor) @ pljava-api ---
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-install-plugin:2.5.2:install (default-install) @ pljava-api ---
[INFO] Installing /home/dataguise/Downloads/pljava-1_5_2/pljava-api/target/pljava-api-1.5.2.jar to /home/dataguise/.m2/repository/org/postgresql/pljava-api/1.5.2/pljava-api-1.5.2.jar
[INFO] Installing /home/dataguise/Downloads/pljava-1_5_2/pljava-api/pom.xml to /home/dataguise/.m2/repository/org/postgresql/pljava-api/1.5.2/pljava-api-1.5.2.pom
[INFO]                                                                         
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building PL/Java backend Java code 1.5.2
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-clean-plugin:2.5:clean (default-clean) @ pljava ---
[INFO] Deleting /home/dataguise/Downloads/pljava-1_5_2/pljava/target
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:3.0.1:resources (default-resources) @ pljava ---
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] skip non existing resourceDirectory /home/dataguise/Downloads/pljava-1_5_2/pljava/src/main/resources
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:2.5.1:compile (default-compile) @ pljava ---
[INFO] Compiling 74 source files to /home/dataguise/Downloads/pljava-1_5_2/pljava/target/classes
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:3.0.1:testResources (default-testResources) @ pljava ---
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] skip non existing resourceDirectory /home/dataguise/Downloads/pljava-1_5_2/pljava/src/test/resources
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:2.5.1:testCompile (default-testCompile) @ pljava ---
[INFO] No sources to compile
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-surefire-plugin:2.17:test (default-test) @ pljava ---
[INFO] No tests to run.
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-jar-plugin:2.6:jar (default-jar) @ pljava ---
[INFO] Building jar: /home/dataguise/Downloads/pljava-1_5_2/pljava/target/pljava-1.5.2.jar
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-shade-plugin:1.4:shade (default) @ pljava ---
[INFO] Including org.postgresql:pljava-api:jar:1.5.2 in the shaded jar.
[INFO] Replacing original artifact with shaded artifact.
[INFO] Replacing /home/dataguise/Downloads/pljava-1_5_2/pljava/target/pljava-1.5.2.jar with /home/dataguise/Downloads/pljava-1_5_2/pljava/target/pljava-1.5.2-shaded.jar
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-site-plugin:3.4:attach-descriptor (attach-descriptor) @ pljava ---
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-install-plugin:2.5.2:install (default-install) @ pljava ---
[INFO] Installing /home/dataguise/Downloads/pljava-1_5_2/pljava/target/pljava-1.5.2.jar to /home/dataguise/.m2/repository/org/postgresql/pljava/1.5.2/pljava-1.5.2.jar
[INFO] Installing /home/dataguise/Downloads/pljava-1_5_2/pljava/dependency-reduced-pom.xml to /home/dataguise/.m2/repository/org/postgresql/pljava/1.5.2/pljava-1.5.2.pom
[INFO]                                                                         
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building PL/Java backend native code 1.5.2
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-clean-plugin:2.5:clean (default-clean) @ pljava-so ---
[INFO] Deleting /home/dataguise/Downloads/pljava-1_5_2/pljava-so/target
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- nar-maven-plugin:3.2.3:nar-validate (default-nar-validate) @ pljava-so ---
[INFO] Using AOL: amd64-Linux-gpp
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- nar-maven-plugin:3.2.3:nar-download (default-nar-download) @ pljava-so ---
[INFO] Getting Nar dependencies
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-antrun-plugin:1.7:run (pg_config to pgsql.properties) @ pljava-so ---
[INFO] Executing tasks

main:

configure_msvc:

configure_nomsvc:

configure_msvc_options:

pg_config:
[propertyfile] Creating new property file: /home/dataguise/Downloads/pljava-1_5_2/pljava-so/target/pgsql.properties
[INFO] Executed tasks
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- properties-maven-plugin:1.0-alpha-2:read-project-properties (default) @ pljava-so ---
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- nar-maven-plugin:3.2.3:nar-unpack (default-nar-unpack) @ pljava-so ---
[INFO] Getting Nar dependencies
[INFO] Unpacking 0 dependencies to /home/dataguise/Downloads/pljava-1_5_2/pljava-so/target/nar
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- nar-maven-plugin:3.2.3:nar-gnu-configure (default-nar-gnu-configure) @ pljava-so ---
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- nar-maven-plugin:3.2.3:nar-system-generate (default-nar-system-generate) @ pljava-so ---
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- nar-maven-plugin:3.2.3:nar-vcproj (default-nar-vcproj) @ pljava-so ---
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:3.0.1:resources (default-resources) @ pljava-so ---
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] skip non existing resourceDirectory /home/dataguise/Downloads/pljava-1_5_2/pljava-so/src/main/resources
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- nar-maven-plugin:3.2.3:nar-resources (default-nar-resources) @ pljava-so ---
[INFO] Copied 0 resources
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- nar-maven-plugin:3.2.3:nar-gnu-resources (default-nar-gnu-resources) @ pljava-so ---
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:2.5.1:compile (default-compile) @ pljava-so ---
[INFO] No sources to compile
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- nar-maven-plugin:3.2.3:nar-javah (default-nar-javah) @ pljava-so ---
[INFO] Running /usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.8.0_211/bin/javah compiler on 26 classes...
[INFO] + /usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.8.0_211/bin/javah -classpath /home/dataguise/Downloads/pljava-1_5_2/pljava-so/../pljava/target/classes/:/home/dataguise/Downloads/pljava-1_5_2/pljava-so/../pljava-api/target/classes/ -d /home/dataguise/Downloads/pljava-1_5_2/pljava-so/target/nar/javah-include org.postgresql.pljava.internal.Session org.postgresql.pljava.internal.SubXactListener org.postgresql.pljava.internal.Backend org.postgresql.pljava.jdbc.SingleRowReader org.postgresql.pljava.internal.TupleDesc org.postgresql.pljava.internal.Oid org.postgresql.pljava.internal.VarlenaWrapper$Input$State org.postgresql.pljava.internal.Tuple org.postgresql.pljava.internal.AclId org.postgresql.pljava.internal.TriggerData org.postgresql.pljava.internal.DualState$SingleMemContextDelete org.postgresql.pljava.internal.PgSavepoint org.postgresql.pljava.jdbc.SQLOutputToChunk org.postgresql.pljava.internal.ErrorData org.postgresql.pljava.jdbc.SQLXMLImpl org.postgresql.pljava.internal.DualState$SinglePfree org.postgresql.pljava.internal.VarlenaWrapper$Output$State org.postgresql.pljava.internal.XactListener org.postgresql.pljava.internal.SPI org.postgresql.pljava.internal.JavaWrapper org.postgresql.pljava.internal.Relation org.postgresql.pljava.internal.ExecutionPlan org.postgresql.pljava.internal.HeapTupleHeader org.postgresql.pljava.jdbc.SQLInputFromTuple org.postgresql.pljava.internal.Portal org.postgresql.pljava.jdbc.Invocation java.sql.Types
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- nar-maven-plugin:3.2.3:nar-gnu-make (default-nar-gnu-make) @ pljava-so ---
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- nar-maven-plugin:3.2.3:nar-compile (default-nar-compile) @ pljava-so ---
[INFO] Compiling 53 native files
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Reactor Summary:
[INFO] 
[INFO] PostgreSQL PL/Java ................................. SUCCESS [  0.413 s]
[INFO] PL/Java API ........................................ SUCCESS [  0.719 s]
[INFO] PL/Java backend Java code .......................... SUCCESS [  0.713 s]
[INFO] PL/Java backend native code ........................ FAILURE [  3.502 s]
[INFO] PL/Java Deploy ..................................... SKIPPED
[INFO] PL/Java Ant tasks .................................. SKIPPED
[INFO] PL/Java examples ................................... SKIPPED
[INFO] PL/Java packaging .................................. SKIPPED
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 5.631 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2019-07-05T18:04:00+05:30
[INFO] Final Memory: 40M/593M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal com.github.maven-nar:nar-maven-plugin:3.2.3:nar-compile (default-nar-compile) on project pljava-so: NAR: Include path not found: com.github.maven_nar.IncludePath@6a292803 -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoFailureException
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] After correcting the problems, you can resume the build with the command
[ERROR]   mvn <goals> -rf :pljava-so
```

Comment: Could you run the command with more logs? The output here suggests `-X` flag to maven.

Answer (score 0):

Well, this is an old question, but for the sake of having an answer in case future visitors find it....

The log said `Include path not found: com.github.maven_nar.IncludePath@6a292803 -> [Help 1]` which looks like an error from the `nar-maven-plugin` that was probably intended to show *what include path* wasn't found(!) but they printed an `IncludePath` object that didn't have a useful `toString` method. Well, it's the thought that counts.

It almost certainly means that something needed for the build—maybe PostgreSQL itself?—didn't have include files in the expected places, maybe because a separate `-devel` package had not been installed. Those would be the things to check.

For Ubuntu or Debian, rather than building from source, it is usually easier to add [the PGDG apt repository](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Apt) and then just `apt-get install postgresql-11-pljava` (or your favorite PostgreSQL version in place of 11).

It would not have helped this questioner because there wasn't a package for 16.04, but there are for more recent releases.